# Storing hours/minutes in a way I can use with NSDate

Tags: time, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm working on an app that is powered by a back-end API web service. There is an entity being used that has a few properties (such as name etc.) and it also has a time. The time is fixed in the sense its 10:00AM but its not date specific.

What do you think the best format would be for me to return this time from the API and be able to turn it into a set of NSDateComponents (NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) easily and accurately.

Comment: What language and/or platform is this? Objective-C/Android?

Answer (score 0):

You need an NSDateFormatter, from which you get an NSDate. Once you have the NSDate you can do what you want with it.